# why underscore says _.initial is Especially useful on the arguments object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

i was reading the source code of underscore i found a comment in the _.initial

```
// Returns everything but the last entry of the array. Especially useful on
// the arguments object. Passing **n** will return all the values in
// the array, excluding the last N. The **guard** check allows it to work with
// `_.map`.

_.initial = function(array, n, guard) {
return slice.call(array, 0, Math.max(0, array.length - (n == null || guard ? 1 : n)));
};
```

i was curious about which case the _.initial is so called useful for the arguments object

Comment: I would contend that that comment is inaccurate. Passing the `arguments` object out of a function to another function (including this one) is not a good idea for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually the `arguments` object is an array but the type of `arguments` is `object` (not array) and the array functions (like slice) are not defined in the prototype of the arguments object. There are many helper method in underscore that fixes this issue i.e provides utility functions that work on both array and argument objects.

The comment purpose in saying that this is useful for arguments object is based on this unification of array and arguments object in underscore js.